# Transformation matrix for a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Working on some exercises for linear algebra, the following is stumping me:
$F:P_2\text{ to }P_2$ with the conditions that $F(p_0)=f$, $F(p_1)=g$, $F(p_2)=h$, where $f(x)=x^2+3$, $g(x)=x^2-x$ ja $h(x)=2+x$. Find the transformation matrix for $F$ in the basis $(p_0,p_1,p_2)$

I don't really understand what's being requested here, or I'm not used to the notation involving polynomial matrices. This seems like it should be a relatively straightforward question but given I only know what $F(p_0)$ is, how do I figure out the basis involved let alone approach the transformation matrix? Should I try to figure something out for the standard basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$ and then do a switch of basis or what's the angle I should pursue here?

Comment: What are $P_2$, $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$?

Comment: $P_2$ is the second degree polynomial space (the whole thing is a linear transformation from $P_2$ to$ P_2$) but the exercise doesn't include information on $p_0, p_1 and p_2$, which is part of why I'm so confused. It only includes $F(p_0), F(p_1) and F(p_2)$; can I just use those somehow?

Comment: No. Without the knowledge of the meaning of $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$, the problem is meaningless. But I suspect that $p_0=1$, $p_1=x$ and $p_2=x^2$.

Comment: Hm, that would make sense given somewhere in the book it defined a polynomial space broadly in those terms. Thanks; so assuming that is the case, how could I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is meaningless without the knowledge of $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$. If it turns out that $p_0=1$, that $p_1=x$, and that $p_2=x^2$, then, since $f(p_0)=3p_0+p_2$, $f(p_1)=-p_1+p_2$, and $f(p_2)=2p_0+p_1$, the matrix that you're after is$$\begin{bmatrix}3&0&2\\0&-1&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Cheers! I can only imagine it has to be this since otherwise the exercise seems to make little sense. The exercise has a second part: "What is the image of the transformation $x\mapsto 3x^2+2x+1$ in this transformation?" Can I solve that simply by multiplying the matrix by the vector "$3x^2+2x+1$" or, I assume, "$3p_2+2p_1+p_0$"?

Comment: It makes no sense to multiply a matrix by a polynomial. Since that polynomial is $p_0+2p_1+3p_2$, multiply the matrix by $(1,2,3)$ instead. You shall get a vector $(a,b,c)$. Then the answer to your question as $ap_0+bp_1+cp_2$.